# cannot figure out the next step

Tags: java

Hi guys so I'm trying to figure out how to get this code to make a bank account but I I only get zero's for answers for the balance and all that, could you help me out. if your wondering I did not allow for an input.

package exercise12;

```
public class exercise12 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account myaccount = new Account(0, 0, 0, 0);
        System.out.println("my initial balance is " + myaccount.getBalance());

        System.out.println("depositing 32.19");
        myaccount.deposit(32.19);
        System.out.println("now my balance is " + myaccount.getBalance());

        System.out.println("withdrawing 90.00");
        myaccount.withdraw(90.00);
        System.out.println("now my balance is " + myaccount.getBalance());

        System.out.println("withdrawing 10.00");    
        myaccount.withdraw(10.00);
        System.out.println("now my balance is " + myaccount.getBalance());
    }
}
class Account {
    public Account (double a, double b, double c, double d) {
     deposit = a;
     withdraw = b;
     account = c;
     Balance = d;
   }

    public void deposit(double d) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    Double Balance;
    Double withdraw;
    Double deposit;
    Double account;
    public void setmoney(double Balance, double withdraw, double deposit, double account){
        setBalance(Balance);
        setwithdraw(withdraw);
        setdeposit(deposit);
        setaccount(account);
    }
    public double getdeposit() {
        return deposit;
    }
    public double withdraw(double d) {
        return withdraw;
    }
    public double getaccount() {
        return account;
    }
    public double getBalance() {
        Balance = account - withdraw + deposit;
        return Balance;
    }
    public void setaccount(double accountmoney) {
    }
    public void setdeposit(double depositmoney) {
    }
    public void setwithdraw(double withdrawmoney) {
    }
    public void setBalance(double balancemoney) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Please read the Help Center. Also, consider using a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Your `deposit()` and `withdraw()` methods don't change the balance in the account. In fact they don't make any changes to any variables in the `Account` object.

1. Your constructor should only set the opening balance.
2. You don't need variables to store `deposit` and `withdraw`.
3. Your `deposit()` method should add the deposited amount to the balance variable.
4. Your `withdraw()` method should deduct the withdrawn amount from the balance variable.

For example:

```
class Account {

    Double balance;
    Double account;

    public Account (final double accountNumber, final double initialBalance) {
       account = accountNumber;
       balance = initalBalance;
    }

    public void deposit(final double amount) {
        balance += amount;
    }

    public double withdraw(final double amount) {
        balance -= amount;
        return balance;
    }

    public double getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

}
```

Comment: so how do I get it to work?

Comment: @user3666564 Access fields you have. The `+=` and `-=` operators may help.

Comment: Im pretty new to java could someone copy my code and make the changes because I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong